# Create arr and filters in JSP

Tags: arrays, jsp

I am making a website which is using JSP's. What i would like to do is forEach through all the items and sort them on their subject.

Example:

**Item 1:**

```
subject = aSub
name = item a
```

**Item 2:**

```
subject = bSub
name = item b
```

**Item 3:**

```
subject = cSub
name = item c
```

**Item 4:**

```
subject = aSub
name = item d
```

What i want to do is `ForEach` through all the items and put all the items with the same subject in different arrays like this:

```
Array 1: {item1,item4}

Array 2: {item2}

Array 3: {item3}
```

Comment: Foreach with in foreach will help you to do this

Comment: And how do i append the subjects to a new list in JSP?